# GLUT function that returns the state (pressed or not) of a key?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, keyboard-events

Is there a GLUT function that returns true/false or 0/1 concerning the state of a key?

Comment: OpenGL is a graphics API; it has no functions for dealing with input of any kind.

Comment: You can use a library like SDL or SFML.

Comment: Since you're using OpenGL, you must have been using some other library to open a window for OpenGL to draw in. That library should also handle the input.

Comment: I'm already using glut to detect the inputs. Is there anything in that library ?

Comment: Yes. I have no experience with it, so I can't tell you how exactly to do it.

Comment: @VincentClavel: No. GLUT doesn't do it. You shouldn't be using GLUT in the first place anyway. It's oooold, outdated and there are far better substitutes.